# Is it ok to run (slowly) with a swollen foot (just an allergic reaction to a sting)?

Tags: allergy, feet, venom

I have read that those allergic reactions are mainly excess of water in tissues. Would it help to do some exercise, and since it's quite swollen (I got sting 3 hours ago by something, the pain is nearly gone, and I really like to run).

In brief, is there a risk of tissues breaking when a foot is swollen?

This question talk about the basic functions of this mecanisms (we don't know if it's an accumulation how blood or other serum in the tissues): https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17032/why-do-bee-stings-cause-swelling